# RecyclerView within NestedScrollView issue

Tags: android-recyclerview, keyboard-events, nestedscrollview, textinputlayout

I add a RecyclerView inside a NestedScrollView and recycler view has multiple Textinputlayout. Scrollview jumps when keyboard comes up and goes down. I have tried adjustPan and adjustResize in AndroidManifest and android:nestedScrollingEnabled="false" in xml but nothing works. Please help me to resolve this issue

Comment: Can please explain in more detail

Comment: I am using recycler view inside nested scroll view. Recycler view contains 10 textinput layout. When i touch the textinput layout, keyboard comes up, nested scroll view jumps(scroll to top and come) and when i press the back button, keyboard goes down and textinput layout goes to bottom of the screen

Comment: upload your XML file ,
why you used nested scroll view?